# What's the difference between "root to:" and "root " in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Example:

```
root 'post#index'

root :to => 'post#index'
```

I am trying to understand the difference or if there's any difference between the functionality of each one. Does it accomplish the same task?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no difference. Here the docs

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-root

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shortcut

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root

```
root to: 'pages#main'
root 'pages#main' # shortcut for the above
```